# What does the @ do in a SQL statement?

Tags: c#, string, variables

For example, when creating a command text for a SqlServer ce statement, the example has you use

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Region (RegionID, RegionDescription) VALUES (@id, @desc)";
```

I understand how to run sql queries, but have always just passed the database system a string with sql statements.  This is new to me, and I would like to understand.  Does the @ mean that it is a variable, so when it parses the string, it will insert the value of the variable id into the string where it says @id?
I know in php, double quotes allow the parser to parse a variable value within a string, and am wondering if this is similar.
However, to test it, I made a simple program to test this theory.

```
string id = "FOO";
MessageBox.Show("@id");
```

It showed the literal @id, so this has left me confused.  Thanks ahead for any help!
I just feel the need to understand what I am typing, not just mindlessly following the examples.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx

Comment: @Rookian, no this is a different post:P

Comment: ugh?! A different post, I am confused :s, but as I can see someone could help you :)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the title was added, but I had asked another sql question earlier.  Hope this clears it up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case `@` defines the variable that you want to pass into your SQL statement.

For instance:

```
SqlParameter param  = new SqlParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@id";
param.Value         = 666;
```

And then you add it to your command like that:

```
command.Parameters.Add(param);
```

Then, in your `select` `@id` and `@desc` will use values passed as a value of SqlParameter.

Therefore, if you just output `"@id"` it will be interpreted as a normal string. It only makes sense while used inside a SQL query.

Answer (score 3):

The `@` symbol, in this case, is used to parameterize a SQL command, *not* for general-purpose variable substitution within a `string`.

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Region (RegionID, RegionDescription) " +
                      "VALUES (@id, @desc)";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 42);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desc, "Description of region forty-two.");
```

Comment: So within an sql query, it replaces the @id with the value of the id variable correct?  That was what I wanted to make sure.

Comment: @Dusty: Yes, but it's not actually performing a string replacement. It's SQL-specific and it's type-safe etc so you don't need to worry about escaping or converting strings to SQL-friendly formats or enclosing in quotes etc. That's all handled by the provider.

Comment: Is this structure SQL Server CE Specific, or is it a standard query language construct?

Answer (score 3):

`@` has a special meaning in the SQL (T-SQL) query (ie: it is used to parametrize the query), but in a C# string you just get the literal `@`. Actually, `command.CommandText` is still a string with the `@` characters; the substitution takes place only when needed (ie: query is executed).

---

If you want interpolation in C#, use `String.Format()`, eg:

```
string name = "John";
string greet = String.Format("Hello, {0}", name);

// this also works
Console.WriteLine("Hello, {0}", name);
```

Comment: Not so much SQL as TSQL, though MySQL also supports variables being prefixed with the ampersand.

Comment: Yeah, I was using the string.format to create the original strings I was using to pass to sql server.  But I switched over to the parameterized version after my previous question.